# Looping a translation file for each xml line

Tags: xml, xslt

As may be evident my knowledge of XML and XSLT is rather limited. Please can someone assist me with a translation file which will allow for each ItemNumber/Sales Order in the below XML to be passed through so that the second XML is generated for each item. In other words, I need to generate multiple output xmls (one for each sales order). At the moment I am only getting one output xml for the last line item /sales order on the initial xml.

Here is the xml that I need to translate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<postsalesorderssct Language='05' Language2='EN' CssStyle='' DecFormat='1' DateFormat='01' Role='01' Version='6.1.009' OperatorPrimaryRole='   '>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197588</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>PV</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000001</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197589</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>HI</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000002</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197590</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>WS</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000003</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197591</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>HI</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000004</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197592</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>PV</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000005</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197593</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>WS</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000006</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <StatusOfItems>
        <ItemsProcessed>000006</ItemsProcessed>
        <ItemsInvalid>000000</ItemsInvalid>
    </StatusOfItems>
</postsalesorderssct>
```

Here is the translation file I am currently using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<Query>
 <Key>
  <xsl:for-each select = "postsalesorderssct/Item/Key">
       <SalesOrder><xsl:value-of select="SalesOrder"/></SalesOrder>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </Key>
</Query>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the required output for each of the ItemNumbers on the initial xml. In other words I need one of these generated for each Sales Order number:

```
<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
    <Key>
        <SalesOrder>197588</SalesOrder>
        <Invoice/>
    </Key>
    <Option>
        <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
        <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
        <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
        <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
        <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
        <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
        <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
        <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
        <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
        <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
        <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
        <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
        <XslStylesheet/>
    </Option>
</Query>
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Your XSLT does not match your input XML. For example in your XSLT you use `postsororderstatus/Item/Order`, but in the input XML the root is `<postsalesorderssct>` so no match there. Also You loop through each `<Order>`, but this element is also not in your input XML. When I look to the desired output this also doesn't match. So what do you want? Or please correct your question!

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? In XSLT 1.0 there is now way of doing this without using extension elements (if you have access to exslt, you could use <exsl:document>). In XSLT 2.0 you can use <xsl:result-document> to generate multiple output files.

Comment: My apologies Mark I had multiple files open and copied the wrong one. I will adjust the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, the following should work...

**XML Input**

```
<postsalesorderssct Language='05' Language2='EN' CssStyle='' DecFormat='1' DateFormat='01' Role='01' Version='6.1.009' OperatorPrimaryRole='   '>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197588</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>PV</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000001</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197589</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>HI</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000002</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197590</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A3</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>WS</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000003</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197591</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>HI</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000004</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197592</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>PV</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000005</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>
            <SalesOrder>197593</SalesOrder>
            <SourceWarehouse>A4</SourceWarehouse>
            <TargetWarehouse>WS</TargetWarehouse>
            <CustomerPoNumber/>
        </Key>
        <ItemNumber>000006</ItemNumber>
    </Item>
    <StatusOfItems>
        <ItemsProcessed>000006</ItemsProcessed>
        <ItemsInvalid>000000</ItemsInvalid>
    </StatusOfItems>
</postsalesorderssct>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/postsalesorderssct/Item">
        <xsl:result-document href="{Key/SalesOrder}.xml">
            <Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
                <Key>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Key/SalesOrder"/>
                    <Invoice/>
                </Key>
                <Option>
                    <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
                    <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
                    <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
                    <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
                    <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
                    <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
                    <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
                    <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
                    <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
                    <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
                    <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
                    <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
                    <XslStylesheet/>
                </Option>
            </Query>        
        </xsl:result-document>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give you an individual file for each `Item`. The name of the file will be the `SalesOrder`.

A couple of examples...

**197588.xml**

```
<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
   <Key>
      <SalesOrder>197588</SalesOrder>
      <Invoice/>
   </Key>
   <Option>
      <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
      <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
      <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
      <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
      <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
      <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
      <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
      <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
      <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
      <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
      <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
      <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
      <XslStylesheet/>
   </Option>
</Query>
```

**197592.xml**

```
<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
   <Key>
      <SalesOrder>197592</SalesOrder>
      <Invoice/>
   </Key>
   <Option>
      <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
      <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
      <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
      <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
      <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
      <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
      <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
      <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
      <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
      <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
      <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
      <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
      <XslStylesheet/>
   </Option>
</Query>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Sadly I cannot use xslt 2.0. Any idea how to achieve this using version 1 please?

Comment: @DevonTrew - If your processor supports exslt, you can use `exsl:document`. See http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this with XSLT 2.0 is fairly straightforward, as Daniel demonstrated. Unfortunately, with pure XSLT 1.0, it's impossible, as far as I can tell, but you can achieve the same result if you're willing to work a bit harder.

(I wouldn't call this an elegant solution by any means, but it's the first method I can come up with for solving this problem without XSLT 2.0.)

I don't know which XSLT processor you're using, so I'll demonstrate with `xsltproc`.

You could first use a stylesheet like this to create an XML file that contains all the `<Query>` elements (call it with `xsltproc allQuery.xsl input.xml`):

```
    <!-- allQuery.xsl -->

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <Queries>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="postsalesorderssct/Item/Key/SalesOrder"/>
        </Queries>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="SalesOrder">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="."/>
          <Query xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
            <Key>
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </xsl:copy>
              <Invoice/>
            </Key>
            <Option>
                <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
                <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
                <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
                <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
                <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
                <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
                <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
                <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
                <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
                <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
                <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
                <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
                <XslStylesheet/>
            </Option>
          </Query>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you could have another simple stylesheet like this:

```
<!-- extractQuery.xsl -->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- The sales order number you pass in on the command line. -->
  <xsl:param name="salesOrderNo"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--
    Only apply the <Query> element with a <SalesOrder> descendant that has 
    $salesOrderNo as its text content -- in the case of this example, 197593.
    --> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Queries/Query[descendant::SalesOrder[. = $salesOrderNo]]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use this stylesheet with `xsltproc` like this, passing in the SalesOrder number of the `<Query>` element you want to get as a parameter to the stylesheet:

```
xsltproc --stringparam salesOrderNo 197593 extractQuery.xsl output.xml
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
  <Key>
    <SalesOrder>197593</SalesOrder>
    <Invoice/>
  </Key>
  <Option>
    <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
    <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
    <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
    <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
    <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
    <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
    <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
    <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
    <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
    <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
    <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
    <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
    <XslStylesheet/>
  </Option>
</Query>
```

You'd then need to call `xsltproc` once for every sales order number you want to create an XML file for. One way of doing this is to create yet *another* XSLT stylesheet:

```
<!-- getSalesOrderNos.xsl -->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Queries/Query/Key/SalesOrder"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SalesOrder">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will print out a newline-separated list of all sales order numbers. You can then use it with a Bash script like this:

```
xsltproc getSalesOrderNos.xsl output.xml | xargs -L1 -I no xsltproc \
-o SalesOrder-no.xml --stringparam salesOrderNo no extractQuery.xsl output.xml
```

In essence, this will print out a list of all the sales order numbers in `output.xml` and run `extractQuery.xsl` once for each number -- with the number passed in as a parameter to `extractQuery.xsl` -- and create a new file (called `SalesOrder-<ordernumber>.xml`) for the result of each transformation. As in:

```
<!-- SalesOrder-197588.xml -->

<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORQRY.XSD">
  <Key>
    <SalesOrder>197588</SalesOrder>
    <Invoice/>
  </Key>
  <Option>
    <IncludeStockedLines>Y</IncludeStockedLines>
    <IncludeNonStockedLines>Y</IncludeNonStockedLines>
    <IncludeFreightLines>Y</IncludeFreightLines>
    <IncludeMiscLines>Y</IncludeMiscLines>
    <IncludeCommentLines>Y</IncludeCommentLines>
    <IncludeCompletedLines>Y</IncludeCompletedLines>
    <IncludeSerials>N</IncludeSerials>
    <IncludeLots>Y</IncludeLots>
    <IncludeBins>Y</IncludeBins>
    <IncludeAttachedItems>N</IncludeAttachedItems>
    <IncludeCustomForms>Y</IncludeCustomForms>
    <IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>Y</IncludeDetailLineCustomForms>
    <XslStylesheet/>
  </Option>
</Query>
```

As I said, it's not pretty by any means. Depending on what tools you have access to, you might simplify this process quite a bit (e.g. use something else than XSLT to extract the list of sales order numbers and proceed from there).